# Как перейти на адрес, не потеряв куки?

Tags: php

Вот код:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://site.com/indexNew.php'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "user=test&password=test"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://pworlds.ru/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "my_cookies.txt"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
```

По идее мы посылаем запрос http://site.com/indexNew.php?user=test&password=test, при этом сохраняем куки в my_cookies.txt.

Как сделать так: сначала посылаем запрос на http://site.com/indexNew.php?user=test&password=test, а потом переходим на http://site.com/test.php, но при этом куки не должны теряться (страница доступна только авторизованным пользователям).

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @JavaBitz Заголовок должен отражать смысл вопроса.

Comment: Я новичок в php:)

Answer (score 1):

добавить:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "my_cookies.txt");
```

Comment: как перейти на test.php после авторизации?

Comment: header("location: http://localhost/test.php");

Comment: Просто выполнить еще один запрос:

    $ch = curl_init('http://site.com/indexNew.php'); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://site.com/indexNew.php");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "my_cookies.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "my_cookies.txt"); 
    curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close($ch);